# Missing tag score

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, badges

By my count, I have a score of exactly 100 in the halacha tag.  But my user profile says I have 96, and I didn't get the halacha badge.  It's possible I miscounted, but I'm also pretty sure I had 96 yesterday and got at least 2 votes on a halacha question today.  I DEMAND MY BADGE AND I WANT IT NOW NOW NOW! thanks.

Comment: Any community wiki answers?

Comment: Also note that these things are only recalculated every X hours.

Comment: @DoubleAA where X is inversely proportional to one's patience and directly proportional to their badge-fever.

Comment: Also note that the badge only counts your answers, not your questions.  Also, the count is sometimes flaky. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: the evidence]

Patience, sir. :-)